# SQL AUTH login fails

Tags: sql-server, authlogic

I am in need of some serious help, and I hope you gurus can help me.

I have a sql server with one instance and I can connect to it using windows auth but not sql server auth, I have checked an the server is config to do both sql and win mode,that is one, but when I log as win auth every time I try to run a query I get this error
" LOGIN failed for user "NT authority\Anonymous logon"

Can I get some help and thanks a bunch

Comment: are you connecting to sql server via SSMS? Login error you have mentioned suggests you were never connected to sql server to begin with. If you were connected to sql server and didnt have permission to an object, you would get an error something like `the object does not exists or you do not have access to it bla bla`, How are you checking that you can connect to sql server?

Comment: Are you using a linked server, or connecting through something such as asp.net, etc? The error you have is synonymous with Kerberos not being setup and attempting to double hop.

Comment: M.ali , I am using SSMS to  connect to the database, I can connect to the SQL server with my windows authentication, then move around DB and check their properities and all but, once I am in the instance, and I try to run a query against a database is when I get this error..

Comment: Sean, I am NOT connecting to SQL Server through asp.net or any front end but using my SSMS to connect to the instance , I can connect using windows auth but NOT when I try to use SQL auth.the server is set to use both win and sql method., How can I troubleshoot the theory of yours. Thanks a bunch

Comment: What SQL Auth account are you trying to login with? Does your windows auth account have admin rights on the server? Have you tried login in with your windows auth account and creating a new sql auth user and login in with that?